# contourf, colormap, colorbar creating a gradation in matlab

Tags: matlab

How do i configure color map and color bar to show gradation of z values from the contourf.

```
     cla(handles.axes1);

     axes(handles.axes1);


     contourf(xC(1,:),yC(:,1),zC,linspace(postTest1.minZ, postTest1.maxZ, 50),'-k');
     colormap('Jet');
     colorbar('location','eastoutside')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to show the same number of color levels on colorbar as on contourf plot. To do this just limit your colormap to the same number of colors:

```
colormap(jet(50));
```